# Can you load aspx files from the database or embedded resources?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, reusability

I'm trying to ship pages, that can be overridden with a base project framework, is there a way to do this, other than gutting the routing engine in webforms and writing a handler?

I am using the latest version of the framework. I know that MVC is probably the answer that will be most used. I cannot use mvc, yet. So I need to try and fit this in Webforms before I propose rewriting lots of sites in mvc.

Essentially I want something like PortableAreas that are in MvcContrib, for webforms.